# How Can I active FBA in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, forms-authentication

Hi I need create a site collection with FBA authenticate in sharepoint 2013
How can I do this simple?

Comment: Have a look at [here](http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/), should be helpful to setup FBA, then to manage it, you can use the FBA pack [right here](https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/). Btw you can use the search box too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tools For use:
 1. [FBA Configuration Manager for SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/28/fba-configuration-manager-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx) – Author and Credit goes to Steve Peschka. The download comes with a ReadMe file. Please read it, since you need to register the WSP that comes with it.

1. [SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/) – Author and Credit goes to Chris Coulson. Here is the documentation that will tell you how to install/activate/work with it. This not only will this make usonly tested the user management er management a breeze, it has some very useful features like password reset and self-service account management.

After install them (for install them U can use document of them) going to these steps

**1. Create the Web Application:**
From Central Administration, we will create a Web Application and call it Extranet.waterfall.net and enable both Windows Auth and FBA. Note the names I am using: ASP.NET Membership Provider Name = SQL_Membership and ASP.NET Role manager name = SQL_Role. You can call them whatever you want, just ensure you use the same names everywhere.

**2. Creating the SQL Database for User Management:**

```
Browse to c:\Windows\Microsoft .NET\Framwork64\v4.0.30319
Run aspnet_regsql.exe
Click Next
Choose Configure SQL Server for Application Services >> Click Next
Enter your SQL Server Name , choose Windows Authentication and type in a Database Name
Click Next twice to provision the database
```

**3. Add Permission:**
    Now we need to add the Application Pool that runs the web application and give it required permission. In this case, the application pool name is waterfall\spweb. Perform the following steps:

```
    Open up SQL Management Studio, Expand the database we created and expand Security
    Right click Users and add a new User
    User Type = Windows User
    User name = choose <yourAppPoolAccountName>
    Login name = browse and choose the login name (should be same as the app pool name above)
```

Click Owned Schemas and choose the following:

```
aspnet_Membership_FullAccess
aspnet_Persolalization_FullAccess
aspnet_Profile_FullAccess
aspnet_Roles_FullAccess
aspnet_WebEvent_FullAcces
```

**4. Editing the web.config files:**
We need edit the following web.config files:

```
Web Application Web.config 
STS Application web.config 
Central Admin web.config <br/>
```

Before doing anything backup these files!
Run FBAConfigMgr.exe. While you can get the code you need from here and edit web.config yourself, if you just let the tool run its course, it will create a Timer Job and do the task for you. In the FBAConfigMgr type in your application URL and from the sample configuration choose the following:

```
People Picker Wildcard
Connection String
Membership Provider
Role Provider
```

We will modify the default values to reflect the following (highlighted items need modification per your environment):

```
Web Application URL - http://extranet.waterfall.net

People Picker Wildcard - <add key="SQL_Membership" value="%" />

Connection String -
<add name="fbaSQL" connectionString="server=SQL01;database=Extranet_User_DB;Trusted_Connection=true" />

Membership Provider -
<add connectionStringName="fbaSQL" applicationName="/"
name="SQL_Membership"
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web,
Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />

Role Provider -
<add connectionStringName="fbaSQL" applicationName="/"
name="SQL_Role" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web,
Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
```

Now You have this fba!!

**Hope this is Usefull!**

Comment: If you have just done this, wow, you're impressive ! You develop a little bit my comment :D Very nice answer, I set it as a Useful answer !

Comment: Because of my friend that say this question to me a week ago with mail I have this ready and do a copy paste and edit:D

Comment: Haha ! Obviously :) But I bookmark your answer, very useful !

Comment: Don't you forget to create a fake IIS site with ASP.NET 2.5 ? I had to do that. Because of SQL and ASP.NET version if I remember ?